# Like GcmIntentService.java used in Android for registration, what should be used in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am not exactly getting what to use in phonegap for android to register to the GCM.
I went through so many links and tried the things, but not working.

In android, the GcmIntentService.java does the job of registration.

I tried the pushplugin by adding the following in the config.xml file.

```
<feature name="PushPlugin" >
        <param name="android-package" value="com.amazon.cordova.plugin.PushPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

But, it did not work.

Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/device.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery 2.0.0.js"></script>

    <script>

        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, true);

        function onDeviceReady() 
        {
                alert(device.platform);

                try { 
                    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                    if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"************","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});     // required!
                    } else {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                        pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                    }
                }
                catch(err) { 
                    txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                    txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                    alert(txt); 
                } 
            }

            // iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(event) {
            if (event.alert) {
                navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
            }

            if (event.sound) {
                var snd = new Media(event.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (event.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
            }
        }

        // Android
        function onNotificationGCM(e) {

            alert("inside onNotificationGCM");

            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event ) {
                case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 ) {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                        // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                        // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                        console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground) {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (e.coldstart) $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
            }

        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
            <ul id="app-status-ul">   
             <li></li>
           </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Following is the Android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pushnotificationdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pushnotificationdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

I get error as `Class not found`.

Am not getting what exactly to use so that it won't be hardcoded specifically for android or ios.

Please help me in the issue.

Comment: For which class do you get the Class not found error?

Comment: Actually it goes into the errorHandler function and prints error. Its not what is shown in android.